# Conditional Binding Without using Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How do I achieve the following:

```
    <ComboBox 
 IsEnabled="{Binding bVisibilty = AnotherCollection.Count > 0 ? true:false}"/>
```

I can use a converter which will be converting count to boolen, but is there a better way of doing than overdoing converter everywhere.

Comment: Looks good to me. A converter that receives a Collection and returns a boolean from the Count property

Comment: in mvvm take this to the VM and have a bool come to the view for visibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use style triggers for that like so :

```
  <ComboBox >
            <ComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnotherCollection.Count}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Style>
        </ComboBox>
```

Obviously AnotherCollection needs to be an ObservableCollection so the UI will be notified every time item is being added\removed to it

Comment: Doesn't have to be an `ObservableCollection` as long as it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind to a Property on your ViewModel and put the boolean and INPC logic in the viewmodel